# How do I return a list of IDs based on missing values of another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

It's been a while since I used R so apologies for asking probably such a basic question :s

I have a variable that has data in baseline, 4 months, and 12 months for the same IDs. I'm essentially trying to figure out which IDs have missing data in 4 months so I can delete those IDs from the entire dataset.

```
   ID     Baseline  4MOS     12MOS
123_ABC   53.5       NA       NA
456_DEF   45.1       32.5     12.2
789_GHI   45.4       NA       NA
923_JKL   88.4       11.1     23.1
734_BBB   45.4       20.1     NA
343_CHF   22.1       16.1     NA
```

I've gotten as far as identifying the row number where there is missing 4 month data:

```
clean <- which(is.na(df$4MONTHS))
```

This is a code I tried afterwards to try and return the IDs to me but it just gave me a message saying "Error: attempt to apply non-function":

```
clean <- list(df$ID(which(is.na(df$4MOS))))
```

Gladly appreciate any help re: this!

Comment: Should all be 4 Mos be missing or any missing in 4Mos?

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon ! There are only some IDs that have missing data in 4MOS (i.e. 123_ABC, and 789_GHI).

Comment: You might have a problem with the column's names having a number as first character, when you use the operator `$`. Try changing the column names or use the syntax `df[, "4MOS"]` for selecting a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

To get IDs with `NA`s(here we assume that all are `NA` not just any NA. In the latter case, use `anyNA` instead):

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(all(is.na(X4MOS))) %>% 
   pull(ID)
[1] "123_ABC" "789_GHI"
```

`base`(no grouping):

```
df[is.na(df["X4MOS"]),"ID"]
[1] "123_ABC" "789_GHI"
```

**ORIGINAL**: Returns where all are not `NA`

A `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(!all(is.na(X4MOS)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID      Baseline X4MOS X12MOS
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 456_DEF     45.1  32.5   12.2
2 923_JKL     88.4  11.1   23.1
3 734_BBB     45.4  20.1   NA  
4 343_CHF     22.1  16.1   NA
```

With `base`(no grouping):

```
df[!is.na(df["X4MOS"]),]
       ID Baseline X4MOS X12MOS
2 456_DEF     45.1  32.5   12.2
4 923_JKL     88.4  11.1   23.1
5 734_BBB     45.4  20.1     NA
6 343_CHF     22.1  16.1     NA
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("123_ABC", "456_DEF", "789_GHI", "923_JKL", 
"734_BBB", "343_CHF"), Baseline = c(53.5, 45.1, 45.4, 88.4, 45.4, 
22.1), X4MOS = c(NA, 32.5, NA, 11.1, 20.1, 16.1), X12MOS = c(NA, 
12.2, NA, 23.1, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @NelsonGon ! I think I worded my question a bit differently but I see what you did here. What I meant was how would I get just a vector or a list of IDs based on those who have missing 4MOS data. (i.e. get a vector of [123_ABC, 789_GHI])

Comment: Thanks so much, yes this is what I was looking for!